# Liferay service builder with generics

Tags: java, generics, liferay, liferay-service-builder

When attempting to generate a liferay service with generic method outputs: e.g.

```
/* ThingyLocalServiceImpl.java */

public <T> T doThing(Class<T> clazz){...};
```

Liferay does not generate the service interface correctly. It erroneously removes the '`<T>`' from the front and compilation fails saying it cannot find the type '`T`'.

```
/* ThingyLocalService.java */

public T doThing(Class<T> clazz){...}
       ^ "error"       ^ "error"
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something? Thank you for your time.

Comment: No, its' not possible with liferay service infrastructure. Your own ThingyLocalServiceImpl service have to return Thingy instance only.

Comment: List<Thingy>, primitive data types and Strings are also acceptable.